# ArgumentError: '1' is not a valid kind. Enum value not saving in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums, html-select

My user model has an attribute:

```
t.integer :kind
```

The user model looks something like this for representing the enum:

```
Roles = ["admin","user"]

enum kind: Roles
```

In the view, I have been using a select tag, to select the role of the user like:

```
= f.label :kind, "Kind:"
= f.select :kind, options_for_select(User::Roles.map.with_index{|role,index| [role.titlecase,index]})
```

**Problem**

When i save the form i get an error as:

***'1' is not a valid kind***

I tried checking the data type of the value that is being sent in the select tag, and it is integer. so i don't know what the problem is.

Comment: your problem is data type only I think. 
try this `= f.select :kind, options_for_select(User::Roles.map{|role| [role.titlecase,role]})`
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any other value that's not stated in your model in the kind enum definition isn't going to be valid. You're able just to create a new record with values `admin` or `user`.

Try with:

```
f.select :kind, options_for_select(User::Roles.map { |role| [role.titlecase, role] })
```

Which renders a select tag with the enum value as is in the model, and an inner text *titlecased*.

Notice, you don't to store your User kind definitions anywhere else. If you define it in the model, you're able to invoke it as a method class afterward:

```
# model
enum kind: %w[admin user]

# view
User.kinds.keys.map { |role| [role.titlecase, role] }
```

Answer (score -2):

`option_for_select` should be `User::Roles.map.with_index{|role,index| [role.titlecase,role.titlecase]}`